# Lumen SQL search query on Always Encrypted columns

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, lumen, always-encrypted

I have a PHP application powered by Lumen framework and trying to query a table that's encrypted using [Always Encrypted](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/DataDriven/SQLServer2016/AlwaysEncrypted) feature from SQL server.

I am trying to retrieve data from a table with encrypted column using `SELECT` query with `WHERE` clause on the encrypted column.

From the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-query-columns-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15), we should be able to do it like this

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Paul';
SELECT * FROM t_users_encrypted WHERE first_name = @FirstName;
```

where `t_users_encrypted.first_name` is an encrypted column with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type. I've tried running that query in SSMS and it works fine.

However I've had a problem when trying to run that query in Lumen, this is what I've tried

```
app('db')->select(
    "DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Paul';
     SELECT * FROM t_users_encrypted WHERE first_name = @FirstName"
);
```

and it returns error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@FirstName'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '2' expects it to be DETERMINISTIC, or PLAINTEXT. (SQL: DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Paul';
SELECT * FROM t_users_encrypted WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
```

Is there anything wrong with the query or maybe I'm using wrong function? or is it not possible to use the built in Lumen library?

---

EDIT:

Turns out based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/using-always-encrypted-php-drivers?view=sql-server-ver15),

> Rely on the PHP driver to determine and set the right SQL type. In this case, the user must use `sqlsrv_prepare` and `sqlsrv_execute` to execute a parameterized query.

So basically we need to use a specific function from `sqlsrv` or `pdo_sqlsrv` driver, using those driver function directly I manage to make a raw query work, i.e. normal select query with prepared statement work fine without need to declare a variable as follows

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_users_encrypted WHERE first_name = ?";
$firstName = "Paul";
$params = [&$firstName];
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);
```

So I guess my question is, is there any built in Lumen/Laravel function that could achieve this? or should I use the driver function directly and probably build the wrapper myself?

Comment: It probably works from SSMS because you have the "Enable parameterization for Always Encrypted" option turned on. Try reading the following to see what's going on when that option is enabled, [Parameterization for Always Encrypted - Using SSMS to Insert into, Update and Filter by Encrypted Columns](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into/ba-p/386124#)

Comment: Thanks, I've found a related documentation based on the clue you gave me. Edited the question to be more specific.